# Passing confirmation to an alert in java script

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function to delete some records. on deletion there is an alert message with 'yes' and 'no' to which user needs to click to delete the record.

The problem is that I want to pass yes to this confirmation without manually clicking on the yes. how can I do this.  please provide pointers.

Comment: You can press the `return` key instead of clicking on a confirmation

Comment: Give the function the deletes the record an extra parameter called say *confirmDelete*. If *true* is passed, require confirmation. Otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying you *should* do the following, but here's how one might try to bypass confirmation dialogs.

Replace the `confirm` function with your own function that returns `true`.

```
var realConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function () { return true; }
deleteRows();
window.confirm = realConfirm;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about native javascript's `confirm()` then, you cannot do what you intend to. If you override the function, you'll not get the popup behaviour.

But if you have a custom alert box kind of thing, then assign an id to the <kbd>Yes</kbd> or <kbd>Ok</kbd> button.

Then you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('yesId').click(); //this will trigger a click.
```

And yes, as Will Newton said, if you don't wanna press the button, just use <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.